# Need to zip and password protect files in as few steps as possible

Tags: passwords, batch-file, compression, 7-zip

I need a way to take a bunch of files and compress them into separate zip files, each with a password (the same password). I want to be able to do this in one simple step.

I have created a batch file that zips them each using 7zip, which worked like a charm, but didn't password protect them.

Is there a command  I can add to the batch file that includes the password? Or alternatively - how can i create a batch file that will password protect the compressed files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### How can I create a batch file that will password protect the compressed files?

Use the `-p` option:

> **-p (set Password) switch**
>
> Specifies password.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
>  -p{password}
> ```
>
> - `{password}`  Specifies password.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> 7z a archive.7z -psecret -mhe *.txt
> ```
>
> compresses *.txt files to archive.7z using password "secret". Also it
>   encrypts archive headers (-mhe switch), so filenames will be
>   encrypted.
>
> ```
> 7z x archive.zip -psecret
> ```
>
> extracts all files from archive.zip using password "secret".

Source [-p (set Password) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/password.htm)

Comment: Thanks! If this is my batch file - where should i place that switch?  for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"

Comment: See the example in my answer :)

Comment: but I'm not compressing .txt files, I'm compressing folders

Comment: @DAE That shouldn't matter. `"c:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" -psecret "%%X\"`.

Comment: beware that this puts the password in your command history. On Windows, this should persist for the current shell, but on *nix, it typically persists longer. additionally, the command line is visible *all* other processes on the system for the duration of the process execution. If any untrusted software is on the system, you may have just given it your secret.

Comment: Any idea what to do if this results in "The parameter is incorrect"?  It's related to the mhe flag, which I want to use but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I know of is like this: http://www.winzip.com/win/en/features/data-protection.html I can not promise that it's the safest but I've been using it for a very long time and never had a problem. Let me know how it worked out

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please try to contain most relevant information from the link in your post. Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).